# Changing the IDCANCEL button to a IDCLOSE button on a propertysheet, taking localization into account

Tags: propertysheet

This might sound like a dumb question. I know that `CMFCPropertyPage` has a `CancelToClose` method but I can't find similar for the sheet object.

I basically want the Cancel button to be "Close" at all times and was hoping to do it in the sheet object.

Is the only way to do this by calling `CancelToClose` in each of the pages?

I read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/mfc/reference/cpropertypage-class?view=vs-2017#canceltoclose) and now realise it is not want I want anyway.

This is what I want on my sheet:

1. A custom **Preview** button.
2. A **Close** button.

The preview button will be to the left side of the close button. I have found a tutorial about adding a custom button.

For the Close button I am not sure what to do.

## Update

So, at the moment I have:

[image: Sheet]

So it has the **custom button** (where the existing hidden `IDOK` button is located). And it has the `IDCANCEL` button. But I want the button to be "Close".

I know I can use `SetWindowText` but I am thinking about localization so I wondered what the best way is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I ended up resolving this issue. I now call this code from `CMFCPropertySheet::OnInitDialog()`:

```
void CVisitsRotaPropertySheet::SetupButtons()
{
    CRect rctOK, rctCancel;
    CString strButtonText;

    // Get the position if the IDOK button
    GetDlgItem(IDOK)->GetWindowRect(rctOK);
    ScreenToClient(rctOK);

    // Get the position of the IDCANCEL button
    GetDlgItem(IDCANCEL)->GetWindowRect(rctCancel);
    ScreenToClient(rctCancel);

    // Hide the IDCANCEL button
    GetDlgItem(IDCANCEL)->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);

    // Move the IDOK button to be in the same place as the IDCANCEL button
    GetDlgItem(IDOK)->MoveWindow(rctCancel);

    // Create the PREVIEW button in the original location of the IDOK button
    ENSURE(strButtonText.LoadString(IDS_STR_PREVIEW));
    m_btnPreview.Create(strButtonText,
        BS_PUSHBUTTON | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP, rctOK, this, IDC_BUTTON_PREVIEW);
    m_btnPreview.SetFont(GetFont());
}
```

The above code adjusts the buttons as I desire. Then, in my `CMFCPropertyPage::OnInitDialog()` handlers I call `CancelToClose()`.

The result:

[image: With custom buttons]